# How to create entity with attachment using RealityView in visionOS?

Tags: swiftui, realitykit, visionos

The challenge is this: Assuming I have a button in the scene, on every tap, I spawn a new entity(added as a child entity to the root).

```swift
class ViewModel {
  var emptyRoot: Entity = Entity()

  func addCube() {
    let newCube = generateCube()
    emptyRoot.addChild(newCube)
    // more code....
  }
}
```

On each spawn, I want to add an attachment to the newly spawned cube(i.e. all spawned entities will have an attachment).

Based on my current knowledge, we typically define all attachments in the `attachments` closure. However, in my case, I won't know how many entities the user would spawn, so I couldn't define all possible attachments when initializing the RealityView.

```swift
RealityView { content, attachments in
    // Load initial content (empty scene at this point NO entities in the scene)
    content.add(viewModel.emptyRoot)
    // At this point I won't have any attachments available.
} update: { updateContent, updateAttachments in
    //
} attachments: {
    // Based on my knowledge, we have to define all available Attachment here and give them ids
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### RealityView Attachments

Use my code that will help you add cube primitives with 3 (or as many attachments as you want) attachments to your scene. However, nobody forbids you to use the regular [text model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67716279/how-to-make-text-to-have-the-same-position-and-orientation-as-box/67716401#67716401) with zero depth, instead of attachments. In info.plist, set `Immersive Space Application Session Role` value for a corresponding key.

```
import SwiftUI

@main struct AttachmentsApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        ImmersiveSpace(id: "AR_ImmersiveSpace") {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

```
import SwiftUI
import RealityKit

struct ContentView : View {
    @State var isClicked: Bool = false
    @State var counter: Int = 0

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            RealityView { content, attachments in
                print("App's started")
            } update: { content, attachments in
                if isClicked {
                    let box = ModelEntity(mesh: .generateBox(size: 0.1))
                    box.position.x = 0.25 * Float(counter)
                    box.name = "box_\(counter)"
                    content.add(box)
                                        
                    if let text = attachments.entity(for: "\(counter)") {
                        text.position.x = box.position.x
                        text.position.y = 0.12
                        content.add(text)
                    }
                }
            } attachments: {
                // hard coding
                Attachment(id: "1") { Text("Cube 1").font(.extraLargeTitle) }
                Attachment(id: "2") { Text("Cube 2").font(.extraLargeTitle) }
                Attachment(id: "3") { Text("Cube 3").font(.extraLargeTitle) }
                // etc...
            }
        }
        Button("Add Model with Attachment") {
            counter += 1
            isClicked = true
            Task {
                try await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: 10_000)
                isClicked = false
            }
        }
        .font(.extraLargeTitle)
    }
}
```

I believe it's the only way to add attachments in RealityView, since all the attachments must be explicitly registered with unique IDs in their own @ViewBuilder which will be executed before the moment RealityView's `make {..}` and `update {..}` closures are run. There is nothing stopping you from creating 100 or 200 аttachments at once. As I said earlier, an alternative to Attachments is to use RealityKit's Text primitives with a zero extrusion depth.

#### Text Primitives

A solution with text primitives is as simple as that:

```
} update: { content in
    if isClicked {
        let box = ModelEntity(mesh: .generateBox(size: 0.1))
        box.position.x = 0.25 * Float(counter)
        box.name = "box_\(counter)"
        content.add(box)
                
        let text = ModelEntity(mesh: .generateText("Cube \(counter)", 
                     extrusionDepth: 0, 
                               font: .boldSystemFont(ofSize: 0.03)))
        text.model?.materials = [UnlitMaterial()]
        let offset = text.visualBounds(relativeTo: nil).extents.x / 2
        text.position.x = box.position.x - offset
        text.position.y = 0.12
        content.add(text)
    }
}
```

This approach has one undeniable advantage over attachments - here's no hard coding.

[image]

Comment: Hey @Andy, in above example we still pre-register all attachments in the `attachments` closure,. I'm looking for a way where we can dynamically adding attachment. For example, the use keep adding cubes i.e. Cube4, 5, 6, 7... and all cubes will have an attachment. I tried to clone one of those attachments in the `update` closure but it gives me message `ViewAttachmentEntity does not support being cloned. Please init a new ViewAttachmentEntity using RealityViewAttachments`

Comment: Can you add UI elements the same way as the Text Primitives example you give, or only through the attachments closure? I think I might just spawn more RealityViews but am not sure of the performance implications of this.

Comment: Hi @shodak, It's not clear to me how you plan to use multiple RealityViews?

Comment: Hey @AndyJazz, within a ZStack inside a regular View I did `ForEach(boxes, id: \.id) { box in BoxView(box: box).frame(depth: 0) }` where each BoxView contains a RealityView that has one box and one Attachment

Answer (score 2):

Remember that this is a SwiftUI view which will recompute when you update a state variable.

To have arbitrary attachments generated at runtime, with all the power of a SwiftUI view, including interactivity, use `@State`. To prove there is nothing up my sleeve, this example code uses timestamps captured at runtime and displays them in SwiftUI-based attachments:

[image]

You can drop this whole thing into a volumetric app's main content view and see for yourself.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var objects: [Date:Entity] = [:]

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            RealityView { content, attachments in
                // Add the initial RealityKit content:
                
                if let scene = try? await Entity(named: "Scene", in: realityKitContentBundle) {
                    content.add(scene)
                }
            } update: { content, attachments in
                
                //1. When the view updates (@State changes), iterate through your runtime-generated data to insert entities and insert attachments

                objects.keys.forEach { key in
                    
                    if let entity = objects[key],
                       let attachment = attachments.entity(for: key)
                    {
                        content.add(entity)
                        entity.addChild(attachment)
                    }
                }
            } attachments: {
                
                //2. Use ForEach to iterate through your runtime data, creating attachments with stable IDs you can easily reference in the update closure:
                
                ForEach(Array(objects.keys), id: \.self) { key in
                    Attachment(id: key) {
                        Text(key.description)
                    }
                }
            }

            VStack {
                
                Button(action: {
                    
                    //3. Update your runtime data as you like.
                    
                    let entity = Entity()
                    entity.setPosition([0,0 + (Float(objects.count) * 0.05),0], relativeTo: nil)
                    
                    objects[Date.now] = entity
                    
                }, label: {
                    Text("Insert Object")
                })
                
            }.padding().glassBackgroundEffect()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Great job, Danilo. +1 from me.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. One option was to do what I do in scenekit which is  to use a plane with a dynamically generated image with any title you like, the problem, as far as I can see, is that you lose the ability to have the swiftui view respond to eye focus when someone looks at it. Unless there is a way of getting an entity to respond to focus that I've yet to find.